# How to use environment variables to fix the error caused by having a space in username when running a command?

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

I'm trying to run

```
yarn create strapi-app --quickstart
```

but I get

```
C:\Users\user' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.
```

since my username has a space in it, (user name). I remembered seeing some method of using environment variables to fix this but I'm not sure how. Are there any other methods?

Comment: The variable `%username%` might work in CMD or .bat file, but it appears that *YARN* itself has this issue. If you can pass that environment variable into YARN, work on that. Otherwise, create a new, less-spaced-out,  user name.

Comment: Something to try.  FIrst, run the command `mklink /J "C:\Users\User Name" "C:\Users\User_Name"`.  Now create a batch file.  First line `set UserProfile=C:\Users\User_Name`.  Second line you launch yarn from the batch itself.  It *will probably* work.  If it works, you can put the batch file in the middle of your calls to pass the command line on to yarn itself.

Comment: I don't know this yarn tool but check if there is an option to pass the username directly in the command line and put it between quotes like -u "YourUsarname"